# Macro line that will remove formula when copying row input

Tags: worksheet-function, macros

could an expert please show me how to prevent formulas in "Daily Report" from being carried over? Specifically, there is a formula in E2, and I only want the data carried over, not the formula. Thanks!!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Response = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo)
 If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
 Dim nextrow As Long
 nextrow = Worksheets("Weekly Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Worksheets("Daily Report").Range("E2:E17").Copy Worksheets("Weekly Summary").Range("A" & nextrow)
 Worksheets("Daily Report").Range("E3:E17").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into `PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of copy/paste with formulas being replaced by their values:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A3")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B3")

    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```